# What will happen if I break a vow to God

Tags: belief

I made a vow to God & I broke it. What can be done ❔

Comment: Related [What to do when a vow of masturbation is broken?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8133/3500) and [Vow (Mokku) fulfillment in Tirupati](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8977/3500)