# Will god Forgive me If I vowed that I will not watch porn but I did

Tags: rama

Please answer the above question
Will god forgive me

Comment: Putting in comments as It's just my opinion. I don't think watching porn itself should come under a sin as long as you don't indulge in vyabhichara (adultery) from its pramad or any other crime in the eyes of scriptures. However, pornography does have effects on a person social/mental and physical well being. It reduces our pragya(concentration), bal(strength) and virya(seed). It is coming in results of many scientific researchs as well. Thus, there is no question of God's forgiveness later as the person's daily life is already getting degraded from immediate Karma, I believe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What to do when a self-imposed vow is broken? Is there a punishment?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8133/what-to-do-when-a-self-imposed-vow-is-broken-is-there-a-punishment)

Comment: Is watching porn once in a while ok