# How to do penance for breaking promise to lord surya Narayana and hanuman ji?

Tags: vrata, tapasya

I once gave vow to lord Hanuman and Surya that I shall stay celibate for sometime ,  but I broke it continuously know iam feeling all guilty  and want to do penance. Please suggest me correct way of doing penance mentioned by puranas and Vedas. Seeking help from many months but i haven't found the answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [What to do when a self-imposed vow is broken? Is there a punishment?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8133/647) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What to do when a self-imposed vow is broken? Is there a punishment?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8133/what-to-do-when-a-self-imposed-vow-is-broken-is-there-a-punishment)