# What is the view of Hinduism on "speaking lie" or "hiding things" among spouses?

Tags: belief, dharma, marriage

Relationship between husband & wife relies on trust.
Does Hinduism permit anyone of them (husband or wife), **to hide things** in any situation? (e.g. if speaking "truth" is detrimental/damaging)

Comment: Speaking or spreading a Lie is violation of basic rules of Dharma, known as ten Yama. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yamas#Ten_Yamas. So definately it is adharma to lie no matter what the condition is, if telling truth is not possible, then one should remain silent.

Comment: @sv. The linked post (only 1 answer so far) is discussing about "information" based truth/lie. On the contrary, Krishna distinguished the truth/lie based on "utter-able". There are stories in MahAbhArata of people going to hell, when they spoke truth for the sake of it(& ended up hurting innocents). The linked post is generalised. However, this post seems more specific to certain relationship. For example, [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8575/1049) addresses the Qn more accurately compared to the linked post. Still, it's up to community, if it should be closed or not.

Comment: @iammilind I just posted another answer there for a diff. POV. But even without it, I think it's a dup. Irrespective of the type of relationship, lie is a lie. A wife can hide money from a husband with a drinking problem to save for future. The intent could be good. Hopefully my answer should address all such relationships and scenarios.

Comment: A great saint once said that one should always tell the truth, but never a harsh truth. Dharma says to always tell the truth, a man who can steadfastly only say the truth for 12 years will realize God. To not tell a harsh truth does not mean to lie - one can simply say nothing or give an evasive, but truthful, response.