# What does Hinduism say about lying? Is lying ever permissible?

Tags: gods

I have a question to a essay I wanted to write about hinduism. 
I dont understand the meaning of not lying. Whats a lie in hinduism? And is it any special exceptions where you can lie?

Comment: Maybe this question might help you: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3848/in-hinduism-what-exactly-is-a-lie-and-is-lying-adharma