# Managing perception compared to executing righteous action

Tags: vedas, dharma, dharma-shastras

I believe on several occasions where those in positions of power focus on managing perception than carrying out there right act. Under what circumstances can it be considered dharmic to manage perception than follow truth. Any examples in scriptures ?

EDIT (example)
So let's say for instance that the head of state announces measures to prohibit social contact in times of pandemic. However he knows that practically it is difficult to enforce it effectively. So best way around it is to create a perception that those not following it are being punished. Is this dharmic ? Or is it not dharmic as it is giving false sense of security to others ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Hinduism, what exactly is a lie? And is lying adharma?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3848/in-hinduism-what-exactly-is-a-lie-and-is-lying-adharma)

Comment: Ok. I need to decrease the emphasis on lie vs truth . What I meant was more on managing perception as compared to actually carrying out the right act.